# wp7 XNA app - Microsoft ad not coming in downloaded app

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am facing very strange issue currently. I have windows phone 7 application, built using XNA framework. I have put microsoft ad control for same.

The issue is, the .XAP file which I submitted to Marketplace; if i deploy that file to my phone, microsoft ads are coming fine.

BUT, when i download the app from marketplace via wi-fi, after the app starts, the ads are not coming.

I verified all and this is really strange. I am clueless and can anyone please tell if has faced such issue?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Can anyone please guide? We are having xna+silverlight hybrid project

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the advertising control on your page? Does it just appear as a black box without ads? I have never used the adevertising SDK with an XNA app before but I know they take a few seconds to appear in my XAML-based apps.

I am including this [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Advertising-SDK-for-91c0d463) link to a sample app that uses XNA and the advertising SDK. Hopefully this will help you out.